# Swift Sorting an enum by its case names

Tags: swift, enums, swift4.2

I have an enum on which I'm trying to sort to give the order A,B,C,D etc. The raw values don't correspond to this order. So as of Swift 4.2, adding conformity to CaseIterable means that BasePitches.AllCases gives me an array of [BasePitches], but if I try 
x = BasePitches.AllCases.sorted() I get the error:

Instance member 'sorted' cannot be used on type '[BasePitches]'. This is true even if I make it comparable and add my own comparable function to compare strings of the case names (rather than using the raw values which would give me the wrong order). Is anyone able to help on this please? Thx

```
    enum BasePitches: Int, CaseIterable, Comparable {
        case C = 0
        case D = 2
        case E = 4
        case F = 5
        case G = 7
        case A = 9
        case B = 11
        // Implement Comparable
        public static func < (lhs: BasePitches, rhs: BasePitches) -> Bool {
            return String(describing: lhs) < String(describing: rhs)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
BasePitches.AllCases.sorted()
```

with:

```
BasePitches.allCases.sorted()
```

Your code is 99% correct. It's just that `AllCases` refers to the **type** of the collection that represents all cases of your enum. What you want is the static computed variable, `allCases` (lowercase `a`).

---

```
public protocol CaseIterable {

    /// A type that can represent a collection of all values of this type.
    associatedtype AllCases : Collection where Self.AllCases.Element == Self

    /// A collection of all values of this type.
    public static var allCases: Self.AllCases { get }
}
```

Comment: 99% correct may equal 100% not working in programming. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call `sorted(by:)` on `BasePitches.allCases`. There is no need to conform to `Comparable`, i.e.

```
let cases = BasePitches.allCases  //[C, D, E, F, G, A, B]

let sortedCases = BasePitches.allCases.sorted {
    return String(describing: $0) < String(describing: $1)
}   //[A, B, C, D, E, F, G]
```

You'll get the sorted order of all cases.